# Raspberry Pi 3 Smartphone LCD

Tags: raspbian, display, windows-iot, dsi, android-things

Recently I was trying to connect RPI3 to a smartphone LCD which supporting MIPI DSI interface. I choose Huawei Y320 LCD (800x480) because of its documents availability and of course the price,
This is the related LCD connector schematics:

[image: Y320-Sch1]

[image: Y320-Sch2]

2 various schematic sources make us sure that's correct.
Then I have designed a PCB like images blow:
[image: SCH-RPI3-DSI]

[image: Y320 LCD PCB]

Backlight voltage is 28V and I think it's OK.
VCI: 3.3V
IOVCC: 1.8V
All other connections from Lcd pin to RPI board triple checked !!! quite sure no interconnection and disconnection.
In config.txt file I have added these lines:

```
ignore_lcd=0
display_default_lcd=1
```

I tried this for windows 10 iot core, Anroid Thing, Raspbian jessie. But nothing happened! just a white backlight. I even tried this code but nothing changed.

```
lcd_rotate=2
```

and resolution setting.
I have checked all DSI pins with oscilloscope but no waveform. changing LCD didn't work too.
HDMI connection is working perfectly but DSI ...
I will be so grateful if you correct me if you find any mistakes,
Thanks,

Here is files if you need to take a look at:
[Y320 SCH1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B34SK583OFYgdURqV0JXRWtfbEU)

[Y320 SHC2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B34SK583OFYgN1NWMkwxTTZWSEE)

[Designed sch-pcb](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B34SK583OFYgRHhQVXlRbW9VSjA)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51528/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-farahi-raspberry-pi-3-smartphone-lcd).

Comment: I can't access chat link for some reason...

Comment: The link has been expired.

Comment: I've undeleted the chatroom several times here for people (it gets deleted automagically for inactivity).  If anyone needs that again at any point leave a comment @ goldilocks and/or @Ghanima

Answer (score 1):

Im not too sure that this is doable, as any display's i've seen for the pi being marketed for the pi that don't use hdmi seem to use the pi's gpio ports and some custom code. I believe that this maybe because broadcom may be using a custom implementation of the dsi interface or maybe because the pi foundation may have only written dsi support code for their official screen. either way you can read more about this issue [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=108&t=133953).